# Controlling Nagios Login Frequency When Monitoring Remote Hosts

Tags: nagios

I've constructed a Nagios remote-host monitoring setup (non-NRPE), and it's functional and useful, except:

Somehow, I found that the Nagios host logs in to various remote hosts, only to log out one second later (if not in that same second), every 3 minutes or so; how often it does this doesn't appear to be deterministic. These logins don't coincide with any check periods I've defined.

From an arbitrary member of my remote host array's auth.log:

```
Feb 25 10:51:11 MACHINE sshd[3590]: Accepted publickey for nagios from 10.1.2.110 port 54069 ssh2
Feb 25 10:51:11 MACHINE sshd[3590]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user nagios by (uid=0)
Feb 25 10:51:11 MACHINE sshd[3599]: Received disconnect from 10.1.2.110: 11: disconnected by user
Feb 25 10:51:11 MACHINE sshd[3590]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user nagios
```

And then, three minutes later:

```
Feb 25 10:54:10 MACHINE sshd[3632]: Accepted publickey for nagios from 10.1.2.110 port 54176 ssh2
Feb 25 10:54:10 MACHINE sshd[3632]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user nagios by (uid=0)
Feb 25 10:54:10 MACHINE sshd[3642]: Received disconnect from 10.1.2.110: 11: disconnected by user
Feb 25 10:54:10 MACHINE sshd[3632]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user nagios
```

I can't figure it. My service follows the generic-service template, which I've modified for a slightly longer check-interval and max-check-attempts. Why is Nagios on this serial login spree?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your host definitions?  What do you use for 'check-host'?  If that performs a check 'through' an NRPE check (rather than something like a 'local' check-ping), then it could be logging in as well.

Also you can check your Nagios log file to see what checks are actually being performed.  I usually perform a 'tail -f nagios.log | grep [IP_ADDRESS_of_target_host]' to narrow the results to a specific machine.

If nothing is showing up there, in a last ditch effort you can enable debugging and check the Nagios debug file - EVERYTHING Nagios does will go into this file.  As the debug file tends to roll very quickly (at least in our install - >6.8K checks), you may have to get creative with 'grep' to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the check is returning a CRITICAL/WARNING state, it could be that your `retry_interval` is set to 3 minutes, which I believe is the default.  Doublecheck your service template in `nagios/etc/objects/templates`